# Is there a way to stop tqdm from spamming in the Command Line?

Tags: python, python-3.x, urllib, tqdm

I just want to download from URL's with a Progress Bar in Python3.
The code that I have atm does not stay in one line and instead prints hundreds of new lines.Is there a way to limit it so that it looks cleaner and maybe changet the design ?

```
class TqdmUpTo(tqdm):
"""Provides `update_to(n)` which uses `tqdm.update(delta_n)`."""
def update_to(self, b=1, bsize=10, tsize=None):
    """
    b  : int, optional
        Number of blocks transferred so far [default: 1].
    bsize  : int, optional
        Size of each block (in tqdm units) [default: 1].
    tsize  : int, optional
        Total size (in tqdm units). If [default: None] remains unchanged.
    """
    if tsize is not None:
        self.total = tsize
    self.update(b * bsize - self.n)  # will also set self.n = b * bsize

def downloader(urllink, filename):
    with TqdmUpTo(unit='B', unit_scale=True, miniters=1,
        desc=urllink.split('/')[-1]) as t:  # all optional kwargs
        urllib.request.urlretrieve(urllink, filename=filename, reporthook=t.update_to, data=None)
```

something like this would be ideal.

100%|███████████████████████████████▉| 8014/8014 [01:37<00:00, 82.29files/s]
(Source: https://github.com/tqdm/tqdm)

Hopefully somebody can help me if this is possible...

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: First hit on google: https://pypi.python.org/pypi/progressbar2 Basically, this uses `\r` to go back to the beginning of the line and reprint it.

Comment: Sorry but that's not helpfull -.- I already read it but I have absolutely no idea on how to do that with an Url instead of a Loop.(I am new to Python)

Answer (score 1):

`tqdm` uses `\r` to rewrite the line each iteration, but different console environments interpret `\r` differently.

Just from a little bit of experimentation with what I've got right here,

```
# IDLE (both shell and from a file)
>>> print("11111\r222")
11111

222

# macOS default terminal
python3
>>> print("11111\r222")
22211

# macOS default terminal
ipython
In [1]: print("11111\r222")
22211

# Pycharm Python Console (ipython)
In [1]: print("11111\r222")
11111
222

# Pycharm from inside a file
print("11111\r222") # Outputs just `222`
```

From the project's [README](https://github.com/tqdm/tqdm/blob/master/README.rst) (emphasis mine),

> tqdm does not require any dependencies (not even curses!), just Python and **an environment supporting carriage return \r and line feed \n control characters**.

and, under "Common Issues":

> Consoles in general: require support for carriage return (CR, \r).

So, try switching to a different console.

---

It looks like you also want to change the design of the bar (or just the color?). It doesn't look like this is supported by the library, so you'll have to either look into the source code and edit it, or try a different implementation of progress bars in Python.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I solved it by myself and I never thought that it could be that easy :d

The Answer is called [wget](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/wget):

```
import wget
url = "https://www.python.org/static/img/python-logo.png"

filename = "logo.png"
wget.download(url, filename)
```

or if I want to use the original Filename:

```
import wget
url = "https://www.python.org/static/img/python-logo.png"

filename = wget.download(url, filename)
```

Now I just have to figure out, how to change the design but thats just optional because I like the design that it has right now.

Comment: I don't see how this answer relates to the question at all, you probably answered to the wrong post